Desactivar boton segun valor de variable de tabla html
Tengo una app con Python en Django.
Template html
{% for avion in lista_vuelos %}


<td><form action="{% url 'cargar_novedad' avion.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" class='btn btn-info btn-xs' value="Cargar" id="boton_carga_novedad" >  
    </form>
</td>



<td>{{ avion.tuvo_novedad }}</td>


Necesito desactivar el boton cuando el valor de la variable de la misma tabla {{ avion.tuvo_novedad }} es "No".
Se me ocurrio agregarle al boton
{% if {{ avion.tuvo_novedad }} === "No" %} disabled {% endif %}

pero no funciona.
Intente con Java
function toggleButton()
//        {
//            var tuvo_novedad = {{ avion.tuvo_novedad }}.val();
//            if (tuvo_novedad='No') {
//                $('#submitButton').attr('disabled', true);
//            }
//        }


tampoco me funciono.
Me ayudan por favor?

¿Será que intentaste con javascript? ¿Probaste usando {% if avion.tuvo_novedad == "No" %} disabled {% endif %}? Más info

Te recomendaria que debugges que viene en avion.tuvo_novedad con una etiqueta p
<td><form action="{% url 'cargar_novedad' avion.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>{{ avion.tuvo_novedad }}</p>
    <input type="submit" class='btn btn-info btn-xs' value="Cargar" id="boton_carga_novedad" >  
    </form>
</td>

a lo mejor debas compararlos en minúscula
{% if avion.tuvo_novedad|lower == "no" %} disabled {% endif %}

